# php foreach loop repeat td's 2 times in a tr

Tags: php, html, foreach, cakephp-2.0

I creating a PDF for print the address of users. I have the below HTML structure:

I have tried with the below code:

```
<?php   $i=0; ?>
    <tr valign="top">
        foreach ($users as $user): ?>
        <?php if ($i % 2 == 1) {?>
            <tr valign="top">
        <?php } ?>
```

But it's now work as expect.

```
<table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td width="48%" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px 10px 15px; font-size:14px; color:#333; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border:1px solid #ccc;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="22%" height="25" valign="bottom">Name</td>
        <td width="78%" valign="bottom" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40" valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="bottom" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40" valign="bottom">Phone</td>
        <td valign="bottom" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td width="4%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="48%" align="left" style="padding:10px 10px 15px; font-size:14px; color:#333; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border:1px solid #ccc;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="22%" height="25" valign="bottom">Name</td>
        <td width="78%" valign="bottom" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40" valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="bottom" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40" valign="bottom">Phone</td>
        <td valign="bottom" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td height="15" align="left"></td>
    <td height="15" align="left"></td>
    <td height="15" align="left"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the abolve table I want to repeat the TD in each TR 2 times and added the blank TR after every TR.

The above HTML out should be the below image:

[image]

Could any one can help me out this.

Comment: try <?php if ($i % 2 == 0) {?>

Comment: @AhmedGinani I have tried this but not work, all the tr and tds is repeating one by one, but I want to repeat in one TR repeat two TD. and After each TR has a blank TR.

Comment: you have to close td alternate try my solution you also need to implement logic for blank td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get properly what you're looking for : `I want to repeat in one TR repeat two TD`
Then this code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo"<table>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

if(($i % 2) == 1)  // odd -> start TR
  { echo "<tr><td class=\"dark\">$i</td>"; }
else   // even -> close TR 
  { echo "<td class=\"red\">$i</td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\">whatever here</tr>"; }
}

echo"</table>";
?>
```

will give you this output :

```
<table>
<tr><td class="dark">1</td><td class="red">2</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">whatever here</tr>
<tr><td class="dark">3</td><td class="red">4</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">whatever here</tr>
<tr><td class="dark">5</td><td class="red">6</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">whatever here</tr>
<tr><td class="dark">7</td><td class="red">8</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">whatever here</tr>
<tr><td class="dark">9</td><td class="red">10</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">whatever here</tr>
</table>
```

EDIT after you comment : added one 'blank' TR

Comment: Yes, excatly I want this, but how I can `repeat one blank TR after each TR`? I want some spacing for above and below TR so want to add a Blank TR.

Comment: Also, how I can use this for the `foreach` loop because I am getting data from Database `users` table.

Comment: @mageDev0688 : a loop is a loop :) repeat logic with your query

Comment: ,let me try with this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution you missed out to close

```
<?php
            $i=0; 
            foreach ($users as $user){
            if ($i % 2 == 0) {?>
                <tr valign="top">
            <?php } ?>
        <td width="48%" align="left" style="padding:10px 10px 15px; font-size:14px; color:#333; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border:1px solid #ccc;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="22%" height="25" valign="bottom">Name</td>
            <td width="78%" valign="bottom" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="40" valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="bottom" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="40" valign="bottom">Phone</td>
            <td valign="bottom" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
            <?php if ($i % 2 == 0) {?>
                </tr>
            <?php } }?>
```